# Python alters pandas DF data when appending to empty array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

While working, I encounter some weird behaviour regarding Pandas DF and append.

The goal is to generate a DF with `RowNum` number of rows, repeating the `UniqueInt` value and generate a new column of consecutive numbers starting from `UniqueInt` + 1 until `RowNum`. This is a way to fill the empty data in between with the same previous data.

My main concern is not how to do accomplish this, but rather why when appending the results to an empty dataframe, the resultant data doesn't correspond to the output from the code (i.e: appending is changing the values of the data being appended).

This is on Python 3.7.4.

I created a really small reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    

#Create a DF
TemporalDF=pd.DataFrame([2,2,3,3,3,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,10,10,10])
TemporalDF.columns=['Int']

#Create recipients for data
BuggedResult=[]
CorrectResult=pd.DataFrame()

# For loop
for UniqueInt in range(TemporalDF['Int'].unique()[0],10):
    # Specify desired number of rows
    RowNum=(10-UniqueInt)

    # Subset original data
    Temp=TemporalDF[TemporalDF['Int']==UniqueInt]

    # Fill gaps of data based on last correctly recorded data
    if(Temp.shape[0]==0):
        # Take last recorded value
        DummyDF=DummyDF.iloc[1:DummyDF.shape[0]+1,:]
        DummyDF['FillIntStart']=np.repeat(a=UniqueInt, repeats=RowNum)
    else:         
        # Create empty data frame 
        DummyDF=pd.DataFrame()

        # Populate
        DummyDF['FillIntStart']=np.repeat(a=UniqueInt, repeats=RowNum)
        DummyDF['FillIntEnd']=[UniqueInt+i for i in range(1,RowNum+1)]

    # Save results
    BuggedResult.append(DummyDF)
    CorrectResult=CorrectResult.append(other=DummyDF, ignore_index=True)
pass
```

With this code, you can see that there are two ways of storing the data:

1. Using `BuggedResult.append()`
2. Using Pandas's `pd.append()` method.

The first element of `BuggedResult` (`BuggedResult[0]`) array is OK and it looks like this:

```
┌──────────────┬────────────┐
│ FillIntStart │ FillIntEnd │
├──────────────┼────────────┤
│            2 │          3 │
│            2 │          4 │
│            2 │          5 │
│            2 │          6 │
│            2 │          7 │
│            2 │          8 │
│            2 │          9 │
│            2 │         10 │
└──────────────┴────────────┘
```

But the second element (`BuggedResult[1]`) looks like this:

```
┌──────────────┬────────────┐
│ FillIntStart │ FillIntEnd │
├──────────────┼────────────┤
│            3 │          4 │
│            4 │          5 │
│            5 │          6 │
│            6 │          7 │
│            6 │          8 │
│            6 │          9 │
│            6 │         10 │
└──────────────┴────────────┘
```

When it should look like this (taken from the CorrecResult table, using `pd.append()`):

```
┌──────────────┬────────────┐
│ FillIntStart │ FillIntEnd │
├──────────────┼────────────┤
│            3 │          4 │
│            3 │          5 │
│            3 │          6 │
│            3 │          7 │
│            3 │          8 │
│            3 │          9 │
│            3 │         10 │
└──────────────┴────────────┘
```

In other way, the append method is **changing** my data after I append it. If you check the code, you can also try several things I already try like following the loop by hand, adding a `DummyDF.to_txt()` method to read the data in separate files, and so on. The logic seems to be ok but it result changes when I append it to an empty array.

Is this some weird desired behaviour of Python 3.7.4? Appending a DF to an empty array may be not recommended because pandas has a solution for that already, but I believe altering the data is too much.

I sincerely hope the problem was mine since I'm no Python expert... so, any ideas on this?

Thanks!

Comment: `append` returns a new dataframe and does not modify the original. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I did it:

```
>>> temporal = np.array([2,2,3,3,3,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,10,10,10])
>>> max_temporal = np.max(temporal)
>>> result = []
>>> columns = ['FillIntStart', 'FillIntEnd']
>>> for x in np.unique(temporal):
...     start = np.repeat(x, max_temporal - x)
...     end = np.arange(x + 1, max_temporal + 1)
...     result.append(pd.DataFrame({columns[0]: start, columns[1]: end}, columns=columns))
...     
>>> result = pd.concat(result)
>>> print(result.to_string(index=False))
FillIntStart  FillIntEnd
           2           3
           2           4
           2           5
           2           6
           2           7
           2           8
           2           9
           2          10
           3           4
           3           5
           3           6
           3           7
           3           8
           3           9
           3          10
           7           8
           7           9
           7          10
           8           9
           8          10
           9          10
```

which if I understand is the result you're looking to achieve.

I'll have to take a closer look at your code to understand what's wrong with it.  In particular, I don't understand exactly what this part is doing:

```
    # Fill gaps of data based on last correctly recorded data
    if(Temp.shape[0]==0):
        # Take last recorded value
        DummyDF=DummyDF.iloc[1:DummyDF.shape[0]+1,:]
        DummyDF['FillIntStart']=np.repeat(a=UniqueInt, repeats=RowNum)
```

This code is buggy to begin with since `DummyDF` may not have been defined yet when it runs (only if `else:` block had run in a previous loop).  I'm a little unclear on what you want to do in this case, since it appears to be dealing with missing values in the range of [2, 10] that are not in your original `TemporalDF`, and I don't think you explained what you want to do in that case.  The fact that you're reusing `DummyDF` from previous loops is what's causing your bug.  When I step through your code in [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) (a skill worth learning to debug your own code), I found that what's happening here: Since you're modifying a `DataFrame` in place, your subsequent loops end up modifying the same `DataFrame` instance that's already in the `BuggedResult` list.  You don't get this problem with `DataFrame.append` because it copies the data into `CorrectResult`, resizing its data buffer in the process.

I would try to avoid using `DataFrame.append` if at all possible--here using a single `pd.concat` as in my example is more efficient because rather than resizing the data on each loop it can construct a single `DataFrame` of the correct size for all your outputs, and then copy into it once.  There may be an ever better solution but it's not coming to mind at the moment.

(As an aside, Python has a style guide [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) on how to format your code, which suggests using lower-case for variable names, whereas CamelCase is typically reserved for class names. Of course there is no requirement that you use this, and consistency matters most. But most of the Python community tries to stick to these conventions, so it's a bit jarring to read code that doesn't).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, the code is trying to deal with those missing values in between, filling them with the same data from the previous DummyDF. For the nature of the data I'm using is impossible for the first loop returns True when evaluating Temp.shape[0]==0, so it will never be a problem (in my specific scenario, of course). I know there can be other ways to resolve this but my concern is not to how do it, but rather why appending the data to an empty array changes the data. Also, thanks a lot for the style guide!

Comment: I just updated my answer to attempt to explain the bug.  It's not exactly clear to me how you want to deal with the "missing" values: if your data ranges from [2, 10] in the first place, why bother with the `.unique()` call at all?

Comment: "For the nature of the data I'm using is impossible for the first loop returns True when evaluating Temp.shape[0]==0" that may be so in this particular case, but as you yourself noted it's not very robust, and it makes the code more confusing and harder to follow.  I would avoid this as a general principle.